# Minimising waste in a cutting problem.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

I have three possible board sizes: $8$, $10$ and $12$ feet long. I want to make some number of cuts to these, say, $3, 2,1,1,1,6,5,3,4,2,1$ feet cuts and I want to minimize waste. I've done a quick review of one dimensional cutting stock problems, but I can't find any implementation with multiple possible board lengths. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to solve the same problem as well. Please let me know if you have found a solution thank you

Comment: check out my solution here: http://www.theboohers.org/quick-solution-to-my-cutting-stock-problem/